# Black Screen after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg, 16.10

What i have done:

- Downloaded Ubuntu GNOME 16.10
- Installed it as dualboot
- Became black screen
- Added "no splash" to start commands
- Installed newest nvidia drivers
- Reinstalled xorg-server & ubuntu-gnome-desktop + reconfigured both
- Generated xorg.con with nvidia-xconfig

My Specs:

- Nvidia GTX 970
- Intel Core i5-2500

My Problem:

When i start it ends in an black scren with the last two log prints on tty1. If i switch to tty2 i can log in. The systemctl says that gdm3 service is running but the child process has been died. In journalctl i found the following message: "Unrecoverable faiure in required component  org.gnome.Shell.desktop"

I don't know what to do now. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I tried today to upgrade a running Ubuntu 16.04 with installed and working nvidia drivers. But i became the descripped error again.